Combination of Excel Table and Conditional Formatting is Slow
An Excel Table of moderate size with some Conditional Formatting is slow in Excel 2016. The table has 16 columns, 20 body rows, and a Total row. Adding a new row at the bottom (marking the entire total row > right-click > insert) takes ~20 seconds. I can see Excel first clearing the cell value and formatting it cell by cell from left to right in the old total row, then in the new row putting the total value, then formatting it cell by cell from left to right. These are 4 times 16 = 64 noticeable actions which take ~20 seconds, ~1/3 of a second each. Only two columns have conditional formatting. One column has three rules using COUNTIFS against two columns in another sheet. Both columns have a rule using SUMPRODUCT against the table column itself. I would understand if updating these two columns would be slow and updating the other columns would be fast. But this is not the case. Each cell action of data clearing, formatting, data writing, formatting takes around 1/3 sec. Definitely each cell clearing and formatting as well as each cell writing and formatting takes the same 2/3 sec. It is as if Excel would re-evaluate the entire workbook at each of these steps.
The COUNTIFS against the second sheet go against two entire columns, but there aren't many rows and there are not tons of empty, but used rows. Ctrl-end on that second sheet jumps to R141, the effectively last used cell.
Can someone explain why this happens?
I could put the SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS calculations in helper columns and conditionally format using their values. I did not try out this option. I am reluctant of adding such helper columns as this workbook is for a struggling Excel newbie customer and I want it to appear as slim and clear as possible. Of coarse, I could hide the helper columns. But then the customer could overwrite the formulas unknowingly. Of course, I could also protect against this by protecting the sheet and allowing updates only of cells he should be able to update. This is laborious. Plus, I never did this in combination with Excel Tables and their dynamically expanding ranges open for update. I hope for something simpler.

Are there any VBA macros running?

The file is an .xlsm file with a Sub() macro that can be called from a button and auxiliary procedures called from that Sub(). But it is not running when perceiving the slowness. When I run that macro it populates data of an entire larger sheet taking also data from the slow table and completes much faster than it takes to add a row to that table.

I also have a couple of macros in PERSONAL.XLSB since long time which I can start in any .xlsx file from a shortcut key, like for instance a brute force password cracker for older Excel files before Excel introduced 256 bit AES, or a macro to put the fill color of the current cell using the RGB hex value currently in the clipboard. But again, none of these are running when I experience the slowness.
